# dnsmasq always returning REFUSED

Tags: ubuntu, dnsmasq

Ubuntu Server 16.04.04

dnsmasq.conf:

```
listen-address = 192.168.5.5, 172.30.108.1, 127.0.0.1 
log-queries
resolv-file = /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
```

/etc/resolv.dnsmasq:

```
nameserver = 8.8.8.8
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

ps aux | grep dns

```
dnsmasq  13099  0.0  0.0  52864   400 ?        S    17:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5
```

Local Firewall ist turned off:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

dig cisco.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> cisco.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 51709
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cisco.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Apr 15 17:26:05 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 27
```

to this dig corresponding entry in syslog:

```
dnsmasq[13099]: query[A] cisco.com from 127.0.0.1
```

I just don't get why I always get a REFUSED.

thanks

Comment: Are the rest of your network settings correct? Last time I had this, it was a wrong gateway that prevented outbound connections, and dnsmasq just was where I noticed it.

Comment: indeed, it was this problem. For whatever reason dnsmasq used the wroing gateway. thanks

Comment: @f0rd42 how did you correct the wrong gateway?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed for me:

In my dnsmasq.conf file, I did not have a `server=` directive in the file. I had to add this with my upstream ISP DNS server ip, restarted dnsmasq and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this fails is because the entry for `/etc/resolv.dnsmasq` is invalid. It must not contain an equals symbol (`=`).

**1. Incorrect**

```
echo 'nameserver = 8.8.8.8' >/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
systemctl restart dnsmasq
dig @localhost bbc.co.uk | grep -Ew 'status|A'
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 29172
;bbc.co.uk.                     IN      A
```

**2. Correct**

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
systemctl restart dnsmasq
dig @localhost bbc.co.uk | grep -Ew 'status|A'
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52524
;bbc.co.uk.                     IN      A
bbc.co.uk.              95      IN      A       151.101.192.81
bbc.co.uk.              95      IN      A       151.101.64.81
bbc.co.uk.              95      IN      A       151.101.0.81
bbc.co.uk.              95      IN      A       151.101.128.81
```

As to a reason for this working on earlier versions of Ubuntu and Debian (Stretch) but failing on more recent ones such as Debian (Buster)? I don't know; perhaps the syntax was tightened up so that it had to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to these problems, that works for me, it is:

```
chmod 755 /
```

that solves all my problems, that I describe, to my delete comment.
the permissions of my root / directory was, 0700,
and in my guess that prevents the user that dnsmasq change its process to, to act correctly.

Another good idea is to find out the if the permissions in dnsmasq's user home directory is the right ones. In my system dnsmasq is that user, so that command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep dnsmasq
dnsmasq:x:110:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

it's going to show me the home dir of that user, (in my case /var/lib/misc)

---

PS:
I make some comments yesterday (but like post, cause my reputation isn't enough), about the fact, that 2 members in this thread, that declare they solved the problem, ignore the request 'How you resolve, your problem ?' by other users, but that deleted by the admins, so I'm not going to repeat.

Comment: If `/` had permissions of `0700` then something had broken it. The permissions must be `0755` otherwise the OS cannot operate

Comment: As you might know the OS in linux systems, run under the 'root' user.
So even if the permission of / is 000, the OS can operate.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here.
Resolved by disabling ipv6.

Comment: How did you disable IPv6, I'm having the same problem on OpenWrt and am unable to figure it out.